# textarea not updating after user changed it

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a textarea like this:

```html
<textarea id="text">some text</textarea>
```

It can be updated by the user as you would expect. But when I try to load the content in javascript, it still shows the original value:

```js
$('#text').text() // shows original, unedited text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently one can get it by accessing `value` on the raw html object:

```js
$('#text')[0].value
```